# "Let alone" vs. "much less" when followed by a verb

Tags: verbs, expression-choice

> If this is Kant's position, it is certainly difficult to make sense
>   of, much less accept.
>   — *Kant's Ethics*, ed. by Thomas Hill

I tend to think that "much less", used in this sense, should be followed by a noun. Here I find "let alone" more acceptable. What's your opinion?

Comment: Depends on whether you mean "much less" or "let alone" -- they do not mean exactly the same, at least in emphasis.

Answer (score 0):

Both *much less* and *let alone* are possible. What is wrong with the sentence is that *make sense of* and *accept* need the direct object *it*.

Comment: This is exerpeted from a Blackwell publication, so is the question you mentioned a  serious one, or just a matter of style?

Comment: It's a point of grammar.

Comment: The *it* is there: "***it*** is certainly difficult to make sense of". I think you're reading it as a dummy *it*; it's not.

Comment: Even so, it would be clearer with a second _it_.

Comment: The construction is much more complex than it appears. Either _it_.